# How to use or convert T-SQL script into a function in an MVC 3 Web App?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, t-sql

I have tried to create this sql script from t-sql to Linq to sql, but it's not returning the same data both times.

The input should be @qid, which is an integer, and @userid, which is also an integer.
The output is each user's latest Response based on DateCreated.

The code that is valid is below:

```
DECLARE @userid int;
DECLARE @qid int;
DECLARE @userteamid int;
DECLARE @questionidList TABLE
( QuestionId int);
DECLARE @teamhistory TABLE
( Id int,
  Userid int,
  DateCreated datetime2,
  UserName nvarchar(35)
);

SET @userid=3
SET @qid=2
SET @userteamid = (SELECT TeamId
                   FROM UserProfile
                   WHERE UserId=@userid);

INSERT INTO 
     @questionidList 
SELECT Questions.QuestionId
FROM Questions
INNER JOIN TeamQuestionRosters ON Questions.QuestionId=TeamQuestionRosters.QuestionId
WHERE TeamId=@userteamid
       AND Questions.QuestionId=@qid;


INSERT INTO 
@teamhistory (Id, UserName, Userid, DateCreated)
SELECT
d.ResponseId AS Id, f.UserName AS UserName, f.UserId AS Userid, c.DateCreated AS DateCreated
FROM  Responses as c
INNER JOIN ResponseDetails AS d ON c.ResponseId=d.ResponseId
INNER JOIN UserProfile as f on c.UserProfileId=f.UserId
WHERE c.QuestionId IN (SELECT QuestionId FROM @questionidList)



SELECT b.Id, b.DateCreated, b.UserName FROM @teamhistory AS b
WHERE b.datecreated = 
                    (SELECT MAX(a.DateCreated) 
                     FROM @teamhistory AS a 
                     WHERE a.Userid=b.Userid)
```

The last Select statement is where the output/returned data should come from.
Here is part of the Response table:

```
+---+---+------+---------------------+------+-------+------+
|ID |QID|UserID|DateCreated          |BS    |Reason |UserID|
+---+---+------+---------------------+------+-------+------+
|140|2  |3     |1/14/2014 04:57:48 PM|0.3200|60 test|3     |
+---+---+------+---------------------+------+-------+------+
|141|2  |3     |1/14/2014 04:58:32 PM|0.3200|60 test|3     |
+---+---+------+---------------------+------+-------+------+
|142|2  |3     |1/14/2014 04:58:46 PM|0.3200|60 test|3     |
+---+---+------+---------------------+------+-------+------+
|149|2  |4     |1/19/2014 12:00:00 AM|0.0000|reason2|4     |
+---+---+------+---------------------+------+-------+------+
|150|2  |4     |1/15/2014 12:00:00 AM|0.0000|dfknl  |4     |
+---+---+------+---------------------+------+-------+------+
|151|2  |4     |1/15/2014 12:00:00 AM|0.0000|dkfjnbs|4     |
+---+---+------+---------------------+------+-------+------+
|152|2  |4     |1/05/2014 12:00:00 AM|0.0000|dskfljn|4     |
+---+---+------+---------------------+------+-------+------+
|153|2  |222   |1/16/2014 12:00:00 AM|0.0000|lksdnf |222   |
+---+---+------+---------------------+------+-------+------+
```

Here is the Question table with only one row to keep it simple:

```
+--+---------------+----------------------+---------+---------+-----------+
|Id|Title          |DateCreated           |Keywords |is_active|Description|
+--+---------------+----------------------+---------+---------+-----------+
|2 |Random Question|10/19/2013 12:00:00 AM|Something|True     |Random text|
+--+---------------+----------------------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

This is the correct output:

```
+---+----------------------+--------+
|Id |DateCreated           |UserName|
+---+----------------------+--------+
|153|01/16/2014 12:00:00 AM|dtaver  |
+---+----------------------+--------+
|149|01/19/2014 12:00:00 AM|lbryan  |
+---+----------------------+--------+
|142|01/14/2014 04:58:46 PM|jsteve  |
+---+----------------------+--------+
```

My attempt to turn this into Linq:

```
int userid= WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name); 
int qid=2;  //question id
int userteamid = (from w in db.UserProfiles
                   where w.UserId.Equals(userid)
                   select w.TeamId).First().Value;

 var query3 = (from c in db.Responses
               join d in db.ResponseDetails on c.ResponseId equals d.ResponseId
               join f in db.UserProfiles on c.UserProfile.UserId equals f.UserId
                        where c.QuestionId==qid 
               select new TeamForecastHistory {
                                         Id = d.ResponseId, 
                                         Reason = c.Reason, 
                                         UserName = f.UserName, 
                                         DateCreated = c.DateCreated 
                                        }).ToList();

ViewBag.info = (from a in query3
                where a.DateCreated.Equals((from b in query3 
                                            where a.Userid==b.Userid 
                                            select b.DateCreated).Max())   
               select new TeamForecastHistory { Id = a.Id, 
                                                Reason = a.Reason, 
                                                UserName = a.UserName, 
                                                DateCreated = a.DateCreated 
                                               }).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and examples of different calls that are returning the different data?

Comment: Ok I will add some to the bottom of the question.

Comment: @BrendanGreen Is the formatting okay?

Comment: And are you looking for a Linq statement to retrieve the data, or TSQL?

Comment: Linq would be amazing, I tried to do it, but i must have made a mistake because the returned values was different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear whether you want to list the most recent response for all users, or just a specific user.

Given the limited data model that you've provided, the following linq queries will do what you want.  You'll have to adapt them to include the additional tables that you want to join to (unless you're not using any data from them, then just ignore them.

**Get latest response for a specific user, for a specific question:**

```
var resp = (from r in Responses where r.QID == 1 && r.UserId == userId && r.DateCreated == (from maxResp in Responses where maxResp.UserId == r.UserId && maxResp.QID == r.QID select maxResp.DateCreated).Max() select r);
```

**Get latest response for all users, for a specific question:**

```
var respAll = (from r in Responses where r.QID == 1 && r.DateCreated == (from maxResp in Responses where maxResp.UserId == r.UserId && maxResp.QID == r.QID select maxResp.DateCreated).Max() select r);
```

If you want to get all questions, simply remove the `r.QID == 1` clause.

Comment: All users that are on the same team should be displayed, but I can make these work. It's just an additional where clause.